# Text Fields and text Boxes in webpage is displayed below the web page IMAGE. The image should act as a background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, jsp

I am developing a web app. I have designed my web page using JSP.
I am using a back ground image. And I have some text fields and text boxes to take user input. However when I am running my code, the image is getting displayed but all the text fields and text boxes are appearing below where the image ends. However as per my requirement the image should be back ground image and everything should be shown over the image itself. Please help.

Below is my JSP code :

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Employee Registration</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function display_ct() {
            var strcount
            var x = new Date()
            var x1 = x.getHours() + ":" + x.getMinutes() + ":" + x.getSeconds();
            document.getElementById("time_div").innerHTML = x1;
            tt = display_c();
        }

        function display_c() {
            var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
            mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
        }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload=display_ct();>

        <h1>Employee Registration Form</h1>

        <div class="Bitmap">
             <img src="Images/online-employee-registration-portal.jpg" style="height: 800px; width: 1355px;" />
        </div>

        <table width="1300" class="myTable">
            <tr class="Labels"><td align="left" width="200"><span id="time_div" class="clock2"></span></td></tr>    
        </table>

        <center>
            <form action="EmployeeRegistration.jsp" method="post">
            <table cellpadding="3pt">
                <tr><td width="20%">Name:<input type="text" name="name"/></tr>
                <tr><td width="20%">Employee ID:<input type="text" name="employeeID"/></tr>
                <tr><td width="20%">Email ID:<input type="text" name="emailID"/></tr>
                <tr><td width="20%">Phone:<input type="text" name="phone" size="30" /></tr>
                <tr><td width="20%">City:<td><input type="text" name="city" size="30" /></tr>
            </table>

            <p />

            <input type="submit" value="Register" />

            </form>
        </center>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background image is position: static.
you should change it to position: absolute; and give also z-index: -1; like this;

```
<img src="Images/online-employee-registration-portal.jpg" style="height: 800px; width: 1355px; position: absolute; z-index: -1;">
```

Comment: Thanks Man .. !!!  It worked. 
However a new problem. The title :Employee Registration Form" is coming above the image now.
Can this also be brought over the image ?

Comment: I got it. The problem has been resolved. I just added the header after the image. It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In my opinion your website structure is not good.
you should add some css like this
`    .Bitmap {
        background: url("Images/online-employee-registration-portal.jpg") no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: 1355px 800px;
        background-size: 1355px 800px;
        height: 800px;
    }`
then place H1 element and others in div with class Bitmap.

Comment: Yess..right you are.. Actually just to run my java code as of now I have designed a simple JSP. More features to add. I will be using CSS.